# How can I get my Fusion Drive switched out for an SSD in my iMac while retaining my Apple care warranty?

Tags: imac, fusion-drive, warranty, applecare

Title says it all. Starting to regret the Fusion Drive. But don’t want to lose my warranties.

Location: West Sussex, Chichester UK.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if this is possible without breaking whatever seals they have in place. How old is the iMac/what model is it? Is it still on the initial warranty or do you have Apple Care?

Comment: Both. I was hoping I can take it to a certified service provider or Apple, and get it switched out to maintain the warranty in case anything went wrong in the future (doubt it will, but you never know)

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you wanted to do it yourself at home. I'm not really sure how Apple would feel about doing it(good chance they'd say no). Call your local store and see or maybe try an authorised service provider. They're usually quite good and they'd be able to let you know for certain about the warranty issue. Sorry I can't help any more than that.

Comment: I’ve got to take it down there anyway because the last repair disabled the microphone so I’ll ask then - probably could’ve saved your effort and asked them directly.

Comment: It's all good. Some people online say it voids it and some say it doesn't. Good luck with whatever you choose to do with it :).

Comment: Please add your location. Warranties heavily depend on the consumer protection laws and regulation of the country/region of purchase and/or residence.